# How to add custom_fields value in JSON API using create_post

Tags: custom-field, plugin-json-api

I want to add/update custom fields values using JSON API,anyone explain how we can specified custom_fields values in url for add or update.

Comment: The question is not very clear. Please add some more explanation to it and if possible try and explain with examples. Also share the relevant codes along with the question.

Comment: Regarding my bounty - I've posted the same question with greater detail here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/166293/how-to-acf-custom-fields-when-using-create-post-method-with-json-api-plugin

Comment: @elzi I created a plugin to support this feature, you can check it out on GitHub [here](https://gist.github.com/birgire/02dfadbcb0ddc3fdb064).

Comment: @birgire Thanks for the help! I can't seem to get it working though. Here's a SS of how my data to POST is set up: https://s3.amazonaws.com/anagram-ss/f3ombv92cLFb9.png


Here's a SS of a representation of a GET when the field is populated through backend: https://s3.amazonaws.com/anagram-ss/fKJhfMEPyD0do.png


But here's what it looks like when trying to post (empty object) : https://s3.amazonaws.com/anagram-ss/vIqTqVZDH8oQx.png


Any ideas?

Comment: I added these lines to help debug: 

https://s3.amazonaws.com/anagram-ss/UZLoW1zIjbAJ5.png

and $fields came back empty.

Comment: More still: Adding this line to debug: https://s3.amazonaws.com/anagram-ss/CM4f3NTzz6G0M.png

Returns 'bet_amount' - the key. Is this whats desired?

Comment: Hi @elzi, did you try using the GET request directly in your browser, using the example in the plugin file? If you're using a POST request, you should replace INPUT_GET with INPUT_POST. I just used INPUT_GET while testing ;-)

Comment: That worked! Looks like I was just setting it up wrong further down the line. Thanks! If you post as an answer I'll reward you the bounty.

Comment: @elzi Glad to hear it worked for you. Since I think the question is off topic and I worked on this also to full fill my own curiosity, I don't think I will add an answer. I hope you can regain the bounty, but I'm not sure how that works. The plugin will remain  [available on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/birgire/02dfadbcb0ddc3fdb064). Maybe I will just blog about the solution later ;-) Cheers.